# Angularjs - How to show nested array on click of Parent array in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, arrays, multidimensional-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please refer to this plunkr, 
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/knwGEnOsAWLhLieKVItS?p=preview)
WHat I want is

If I click of Reading Korean then it should display its nested part i.e. Vowels,Consonants,Simple Words,Harder Words

```js
angular.module('Tutorials', []).controller('getAnswers', function ($scope, $element) {
    $scope.sectionNumber = 0;
    $scope.tutorialNumber = 0;
  $scope.questionNumber = 0;
 $scope.sections = sections;
 $scope.loadFromMenu = function (tut) {
      alert(tut);
   if (tut === $scope.tutorialNumber && tut !== 0) {
    return;
   } //if clicked on already playing tut
   if (tut !== undefined) {
    $scope.tutorialNumber = tut;
   }
   var section = sections[$scope.sectionNumber];
   for (var i in section.tutorials) {
    section.tutorials[i].active = "inactive";
   }
   section.active = "active";
   section.tutorials[$scope.tutorialNumber].active = "active";
   $scope.$apply();
   $scope.questionNumber = 0;
   if ($scope.sectionNumber === 1){
    conjugationController();
   }
  };

});

var sections = [{
    active: "inactive",
    name: "Reading Korean",
  romanizeService: "http://www.kawa.net/works/ajax/romanize/romanize.cgi?q=%ED%96%88%EB%8B%A4?&mode=hangul",
    tutorials: [{
        active: "inactive",
        name: "Vowels"
    },{
        active: "inactive",
        name: "Consonants"
    },{
        active: "inactive",
        name: "Simple Words"
    },{
        active: "inactive",
        name: "Harder Words"
    }]
},{
 active: "inactive",
 name: "Conjugations",
 tutorials: [{
  active: "inactive",
  name: "ㅗ and ㅏ regular",
  verbs: ["작다", "놀다", "닦다"]
 }, {
  active: "inactive",
  name: "ㅜ, ㅓ and ㅣ regular",
  verbs: ["웃다", "울다", "멀다"]
 }, {
  active: "inactive",
  name: "ㅏ and ㅓ reductive"
 }, {
  active: "inactive",
  name: "ㅗ and ㅜ reductive"
 }, {
  active: "inactive",
  name: "ㅣ reductive"
 }]
}, {
 active: "inactive",
 name: "Sentence Building",
 tutorials: [{
  active: "inactive",
  name: "Particles"
 }, {
  active: "inactive",
  name: "Word Order"
 }]
}];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Tutorials">
  
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script-ng.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-controller="getAnswers">
    <ul ng-repeat="section in sections" ng-init="sectionIndex = $index">
      <li  class="section_title {{section.active}}" >
          {{section.name}}
      </li>
      <ul>
        <li class="tutorial_title {{tutorial.active}}" ng-click="loadFromMenu(sectionIndex)" ng-repeat="tutorial in section.tutorials">
              {{tutorial.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

And similar to remaining two Conjugations and Sentence Building. Until and unless I dont click it shoudnt show its nested array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this: ??

```js
angular.module('Tutorials', []).controller('getAnswers', function ($scope, $element) {
    $scope.sectionNumber = 0;
    $scope.tutorialNumber = 0;
  $scope.questionNumber = 0;
 $scope.sections = sections;
 $scope.loadFromMenu = function (tut) {
      alert(tut);
   if (tut === $scope.tutorialNumber && tut !== 0) {
    return;
   } //if clicked on already playing tut
   if (tut !== undefined) {
    $scope.tutorialNumber = tut;
   }
   var section = sections[$scope.sectionNumber];
   for (var i in section.tutorials) {
    section.tutorials[i].active = "inactive";
   }
   section.active = "active";
   section.tutorials[$scope.tutorialNumber].active = "active";
   $scope.$apply();
   $scope.questionNumber = 0;
   if ($scope.sectionNumber === 1){
    conjugationController();
   }
  };

});

var sections = [{
    active: "inactive",
    name: "Reading Korean",
  expand: true,
  romanizeService: "http://www.kawa.net/works/ajax/romanize/romanize.cgi?q=%ED%96%88%EB%8B%A4?&mode=hangul",
    tutorials: [{
        active: "inactive",
        name: "Vowels"
    },{
        active: "inactive",
        name: "Consonants"
    },{
        active: "inactive",
        name: "Simple Words"
    },{
        active: "inactive",
        name: "Harder Words"
    }]
},{
 active: "inactive",
 name: "Conjugations",
 tutorials: [{
  active: "inactive",
  name: "ㅗ and ㅏ regular",
  verbs: ["작다", "놀다", "닦다"]
 }, {
  active: "inactive",
  name: "ㅜ, ㅓ and ㅣ regular",
  verbs: ["웃다", "울다", "멀다"]
 }, {
  active: "inactive",
  name: "ㅏ and ㅓ reductive"
 }, {
  active: "inactive",
  name: "ㅗ and ㅜ reductive"
 }, {
  active: "inactive",
  name: "ㅣ reductive"
 }]
}, {
 active: "inactive",
 name: "Sentence Building",
 tutorials: [{
  active: "inactive",
  name: "Particles"
 }, {
  active: "inactive",
  name: "Word Order"
 }]
}];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Tutorials">
  
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script-ng.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-controller="getAnswers">
    <ul ng-repeat="section in sections" ng-init="sectionIndex = $index">
      <li  class="section_title {{section.active}}" ng-click="section.expand=!section.expand" >
          {{section.name}}
      </li>
      <ul ng-show="section.expand">
        <li class="tutorial_title {{tutorial.active}}" ng-click="loadFromMenu(sectionIndex)" ng-repeat="tutorial in section.tutorials">
              {{tutorial.name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: yes exactly.Thanks for this. Moreover one more thing if you can help. I want by default Reading Korean and child should be shown should be shown.  @MeTe-30

Comment: @Mohammed I don't know your limits, but adding `expand: true` to Reading Korean will solve the problem, check the updates.

Comment: I want a small change in this. If I click on any section.name then other section.name's tutorial list should be hide and that clicked section.name's tutorial list should display.  @MeTe-30